# Does a Kappa Architecture use a data lake or not?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, data-processing, data-lake, kappa

Kukreja in “Data Engineering with Apache Spark, Delta Lake, and Lakehouse” says that a Kappa architecture has no data lake. Microsoft in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/big-data (see picture) mentions a “long term store” without saying what it actually is. It uses that data to “re-compute”. For me this is a data lake.

Does a Kappa Architecture use a data lake or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.

But others have a more realistic perception. It states recompute... Imagine a mistake has been made, handy to be able to correct. From the long term store.

Comment: The "From the long term store" is a datalake?

Comment: Interesting point. I think not in this context as you know schema. Confusing for sure.

Comment: What means "as you know schema"?

Comment: As you know the data format. I n schema on read you just dump data and work it out later.